# WSO2 API manager behind nginx

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've got:
- a WSO2 API MAnager 1.3 on a host in a private LAN.
- an nginx host with two NIC one on the same private ALN of the API manager and another with a public IP.

I need to set up the environment so that it will be possible to access the API store and publisher (and even the management through the nginx host using a proxy pass).

How do I have to configure the files in the API manager (and possible the rules also for niginx).
Considering also that the API will have to be published with the public address and also the Authorization token need to be created so that it will be accepted by users calling the public address.
Lets suppose that the public address is www.public.eu (194.1.1.150) and the private LAN is apimanager.private.local (10.1.1.141). I will keep the same port for sake of easiness, but it could be nice to have indications on how to change ports.
I've tryed to modify ap-manager.xml, carbon.xml and axix2.xml with no success.
Thanks
Luca

Comment: Can you please check with, mcastBindAddress as local IP and localMemberHost as Public IP?

Comment: You need to configure `<APIEndpointURL>` in api-manager.xml. Detailed instructions can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577121/wso2-api-manager-displaying-correct-ip-in-ui