# WSO2 API Manager - Displaying correct IP in UI

Tags: wso2

Have installed the API manager 1.4.0 on a single machine and got everything running. However have found the IP address shown within the management console and store sites are incorrect. For instance in the mgnt console home page the 'Host' and 'Server URL', also on an api's page in the store (both the URLs provides in the overview and the ip used in the 'try it' feature).

Looking into this it seems my network adapter is supplying a privately accessible ip, instead of public (this cannot be changed). This value is then propagated around the API manager on startup between components but also to provide links to access the services externally.

Have looked into the configuration and changed some values, however cannot get all IP's in the UI to display correct. Settings I've changed include..

```
repository\conf\carbon.xml HostName, MgtHostName, ServerURL

repository\conf\api-manager.xml APIGateway-->APIEndpointURL (also updated APIKeyManager-->ThriftServerHost)
```

Is there any way to solve this? In particular, is there a way to set an IP that will be published for external access without changing any configuration used for communications within the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an IP address, I would use a domain name, and add it first to your hosts file like:

```
192.168.1.2 apimanager.example.net
```

Then edit some carbon.xml parameters to look like:

```
<HostName>apimanager.example.net</HostName>

<MgtHostName>apimanager.example.net</MgtHostName>

<ServerURL>https://apimanager.example.net:${carbon.management.port}${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Have given this a go and the values in the mngt console show correctly, however all store values remain incorrect. Also applied the same changes to the api-manager.xml APIEndpointURL and this successfully updated the values published in the api store page, however not the 'Try it now' form. Then went on a crazy mission and updated all references to ${carbon.local.ip} in the whole api manager folder. Still no joy. Can't help feeling that the MgtHostName value should be used for the published url value, but is not. Can anyone from wso2 comment?

Comment: Ok, so hadn't realised the 'try it now' section was swagger. Went back to the api's documentation, edited the API Definition document's basePath and it worked. So gathered this was set when the api was created and the api manager had incorrect values. Have recreated the api now it does have the correct baseURL.